# How to keep a fixed element's child position fixed? (iOS web)

Tags: ios, css

I used fixed position on a sidenav on am mobile site designed for iOS devices. For developers who are familiar with iOS web engine, they should know that once a parent element is set to have `overflow:hidden`, the entire element will become unscrollable even if one of its child element has `overflow:scroll` attribute.

```
<md-sidenav md-component-id="left">
  <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h2>Menu Control Center</h2>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <section>
    <md-switch id="nsfw">NSFW</md-switch>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
      <md-content  md-ink-ripple><div class='navBtn' layout-align="start center">
        One
      </div></md-content>
      <md-content  md-ink-ripple><div class='navBtn' layout-align="start center">
        Two
      </div></md-content>
      <md-content  md-ink-ripple><div class='navBtn' layout-align="start center">
        Three
      </div></md-content>
      <md-content  md-ink-ripple><div class='navBtn' layout-align="start center">
        Four
      </div></md-content>
      <md-content  md-ink-ripple><div class='navBtn' layout-align="start center">
        Five
      </div></md-content>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-content id="navFooter">
      <p>© copyright</p>
    </md-content>
  </section>
</md-sidenav>
```

So the `md-toolbar` is the child element I like to stay on top while `section` is the part where users can scroll if they have very low resolution screens. I realized the `md-toolbar` will get scrolled while set to a fixed position. On desktop, I can set `md-toolbar` to `overflow:hidden` and allow the `section` to do `overflow:scroll` but on an iOS it will not work. The behavior is that the user will be able to scroll the entire `md-toolbar` away, as well as scrolling the elements behind it while visually seeing this elements, and the `md-toolbar` will bounce back when they release their thumb.

For those who doesn't understand how iOS web behaves here are the example:

[image: Original position]
[image: Scrolling position]

As you can see when `md-toolbar` to `overflow:hidden` and allow the `section` to do `overflow:scroll` the element on the menu are not being scrolled, the elements behind the menu are the ones being scrolled.

And for those who want to see a desktop example of the correct behavior please see this demo page: http://photo.aerofotea.com

Comment: No what you are mentioning about overflow property regarding IOS is wrong.

Comment: Sorry what i have said for IOS devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good reason why major websites like Facebook or Google decided against using fixed position menu, because the web engine on iOS is fundamentally flawed. But there is a way around it, and only if you decided to have the menu's height set to 100% (and it looks like you are).

On the first step, set the `md-sidenav` element to 100% height. And then set the `section` element also to 100% height, then set `overflow: scroll`. This will make sure the iOS does not disable scrolling on your `md-sidenav` while allow its child element to scroll when overflow happens.

But there are still flaws in this solution. For example if the user scroll at "menu control center" area, they will still scroll the elements behind the menu and scroll the menu off the screen. Until Apple gets its acts together, this is the best solution we have.